# Error calling third party webservice asmx from production server, no error from development machine

Tags: web-services, exception, visual-studio-2005, asmx, firewall

In a VS2005 VB.NET project we are consuming a third party asmx-service to transform account numbers.

On the development machine everything works fine, but on the production server an exception is thrown when we call the service.

This is the exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at KlantenApplicatie.BL.IbanConversie.IBANBIC.calculateIBAN1(String ISOcountry, String account)
   at KlantenApplicatie.BL.Relatie.SpecGegFiscTOWBasisinfoBL.convertToIban(String rekeningNummer)
```

It takes some time for the exception to appear.

The webservice is: http://www.ebcs.be/iban/IBANBIC.asmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong configuration of the proxy in internet explorer.
When I adjusted this everything worked fine.